# How can you inhibit crystallisation of hot superconcentrated magnesium sulphate

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, crystal-structure

I’m trying to create a gel like solution of primarily magnesium sulphate heptahydrate or Epsom salt and water.  It’s simple to create a hot super concentrated solution but when it cools it’s obviously begins to crystallise. Continuous stirring as it cools and cooling quickly creates a slush of tiny granules which eventually settle to the bottom of the solution like sand in water if too thin.

How can a thick concentrated smooth liquid be created?

I’ve looked into ways of inhibiting crystal formation but no good examples.  Maybe an impurity if some kind and then possibly a thickener if the mix is still watery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your question involves **in**organic chemistry, not organic, unless you're talking about the unmentioned gelling agent.

Second: Impurities serve as a source of nucleation, and stirring *increases* crystallization. If you leave the *supersaturated* solution in a clean container and allow it to cool *slowly*, e.g. in a Styrofoam cooler chest, it may take a long time to form crystals. If you use some thickener, such as PEG or gelatin, it might take longer yet. Left undisturbed, though, supersaturated $\ce{MgSO4}$ can persist for years. There are [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vt-ulVPYvLY) of it crystallizing after a seed is added.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I’m obviously not a chemist so your help with this is more than useful. You’ve given a direction so thank you again. Much appreciated.

Comment: Just a quick update. I found that cooling this super saturated solution slowly did leave some solution as liquid but it actually caused much larger crystals to form also. It would be fantastic if it could all be kept as a liquid solution. I read somewhere that adding cellulose can do this. I don’t need a good safe solution in particular, anything within reason could be added.

Comment: Amendment for above “Food safe”

Comment: If the supersaturated solution contains no seed crystals, i.e. it is heated until *all* the Epsom salt dissolves, it should not recrystallize until "provoked" (e.g. shaking, stirring, scratching the side of the container, dropping in a seed crystal).